p5 using WEBGL mode creates too many canvas in React
I'm having a problem with my code where I am using P5-wrapper/react to show the 2D model I created. However, whenever React states changes it re-creates the canvas again and again it gives warning that WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost..
My code is a bit complex, thus I have created a simple example in this codesandbox, but I will also give a bit information.
I got Measurement class where I am using to set up specific measurement objects.
class Measurement {
  constructor(p5, initVariables, onChangeDraw, _ref) {
    this.p5 = p5;
    this.initVariables = initVariables;
    this.onChangeDraw = onChangeDraw;
    this.ref = _ref;
    this.pointActive = false;
    this.activePoint = this.p5.createVector(0, 0);
  }

  checkPoints() {
    if (
      this.p5.dist(
        this.p5.mouseX,
        this.p5.mouseY,
        this.ref.x + 300,
        this.ref.y + 250
      ) < 26
    ) {
      this.activePoint = this.ref.x;
      this.pointActive = true;

      if (this.initVariables.mP) {
        this.ref.x = this.p5.mouseX - 300;
        this.ref.y = this.p5.mouseY - 250;
      }
    } else {
      this.pointActive = false;
    }

    if (this.initVariables.mP && this.onChangeDraw && this.pointActive) {
      this.onChangeDraw();
    }
  }

  drawMeasurement() {
    if (this.pointActive) {
      this.p5.noStroke();
      this.p5.fill(0, 20);
      this.p5.circle(this.ref.x, this.ref.y, 13);
    }
    this.p5.stroke(255, 0, 0);
    this.p5.fill(255, 0, 0);
    this.p5.strokeWeight(2);
    this.p5.circle(this.ref.x, this.ref.y, 5);
    this.p5.noFill();
  }
}

and some variables and function:
const mM = [];
let dataDimensions = [];
let setDataDimensions;

let initVariables = {
  mP: false,
};

const onChangeDraw = () => {
  setDataDimensions([...dataDimensions]);
};

and I have this sketch function I am using:
const sketch = (p5, measurements, setMeasurements) => {
  p5.setup = () => {
        measurements.map((measurement) => {
      const name = new Measurement(
        p5,
        initVariables,
        onChangeDraw,
        measurement.ref
      );
      mM.push(name);
    });
    dataDimensions = measurements;
    setDataDimensions = setMeasurements;
    p5.createCanvas(600, 500, p5.WEBGL);
  };

  p5.draw = () => {
    p5.background(237, 239, 237);
    p5.stroke(0);
    p5.strokeWeight(2);
    p5.circle();
    p5.beginShape();

    for (let m of mM) {
      m.drawMeasurement();
      m.checkPoints();
    }

    mM.map((measurement) => p5.vertex(measurement.ref.x, measurement.ref.y));
    p5.endShape(p5.CLOSE);
  };

  p5.mousePressed = () => {
    initVariables.mP = true;
  };
  p5.mouseReleased = async () => {
    initVariables.mP = false;
  };
};

problem seems to be once I click and drag any point where state changes because of onChangeDraw where I set the measurements into new measurements I get from p5 side.
So, also including measurements for reference:
const [measurements, setMeasurements] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      ref: {
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      ref: {
        x: 200,
        y: 100,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      ref: {
        x: 200,
        y: 200,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      ref: {
        x: 100,
        y: 200,
      },
    },
  ]);

and wrapper:
<div className="App">
      <ReactP5Wrapper
        sketch={(p5) => sketch(p5, measurements, setMeasurements)}
      />
    </div>


I don't see any teardown/cleanup code, so when the component unmounts and remounts the p5 canvas will leak.

@ggorlen well, i found the solution myself. had to use useMemo and updateWithProps.

The solution was rather simple that I imagined. I had to use updateWithProps  which is mentioned in Wrapper.
So, it could be like:
 <ReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketch} measurements={dimensions} setMeasurements={setDimensions} />

and
const sketch = (p5) => {}
    p5.updateWithProps = props => {
        dataDimensions = props.measurements;
        setDataDimensions = props.setMeasurements;
    };

